# iOS: How do I change keyboard type?

Tags: ios

iOS: I have a problem changing my keyboard type.

It is quite simple to do if the input is into a UITextfield, e.g.

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

but I am NOT using a UITextfield. (All the examples I’ve seen are for UITextFields.)

I click on an array of numbers and, getting the row, column indices, wait for input provided by the UIKeyInput protocol, i.e. using its canBecomeFirstResponder, hasText, and insertText methods.

It works fine, but I get the default keyboard.

The keyboardType property is in UITextInputTraits, but I don’t know to get to it.

Comment: maybe your UITextView?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what you actually have. And show some relevant code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question -- why the downvotes?

Comment: @Caleb Nothing wrong? This question is unclear and provides little information about what is causing the problem. Your own answer is making assumptions because it is unclear what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using the keyboard for your own custom view rather than an existing view, implement the [`UITextInputTraits` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) in your view. Then your view will have a `keyboardType` property just like `UITextField` and others.